# Two networks, same subnet, how is a host resolved?

Tags: networking

A machine is physically connected to...

FooNET w/subnet of 192.168.1.0
and
BarNET w/subnet of 192.168.1.0

via let's say two gigabit nics.

I try to ssh into a server at 192.168.1.140...

```
ssh admin@192.168.1.140
```

How does the system determine which network the server is on?

What if another server happens to be at 192.168.1.140 on both networks?

EDIT: Let me expand on my actual situation. I tried to make this generic so that it would be more helpful to others, but in this situation more information is needed.

I have a web-server VM called Eureka running on VMWare Fusion on a MacBook Pro. Eureka has been configured to have two virtual nics, one is for public traffic and connects Eureka directly to my real physical network via DHCP.

The other connection Eureka has connects only Eureka and the Mac on a private virtual network. Eureka is configured with a static IP on this network, the IP is 192.168.1.250

Both the physical network and the virtual network are currently configured to use 192.168.1.0/24, it's also worth noting that these networks are not attached, the host machine (the MacBook) and Eureka can access both networks, but beyond that the networks are distinct.

My question was somewhat hypothetical, I really just wanted to know how this situation is resolved. I don't actually currently have another server on either network @ 192.168.1.250.

However this does bring me to an interesting conclusion, I suppose even though the networks are separate, I should probably separate them onto different subnets just so no collisions can occur.

Comment: You're not getting me, in this case the machine is connected to TWO ENTIRELY DIFFERENT NETWORKS, it has an IP on BOTH OF THEM and therefore belongs to TWO NETWORKS. It doesn't have a single subnet, there are two of them. Also this is a very serious question, based on a real situation I'm in.

Comment: So, both networks are addressed the same? How is the routing configured on that single server?

Comment: Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: @CodySmith - Your guess about narrowing your masks to make two separate subnets is a good one.  As long as there is subnet overlap (in your original case total overlap) then you are going to have routing problems that you can't avoid.  Whichever NIC is listed with higher priority (or first if they are equal) will tend to get ALL outbound traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the machine you are ssh'ing from and server are directly connected to both the FooNET and BarNet networks (both have dual NIC's), to determine which network would be used, you need to review the routing table on the machine you are ssh'ing from.  This will provide you with the interface that the packets will be sent from and therefore the physical network.  For example on my laptop at home, I am connected to the local subnet 192.168.152.0/24.  The route onto the 192.168.152 network is via my en0 interface as show on the last line  below:

```
vincent:~ scott$ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.152.1      UGSc           17        0     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              8  4676557     lo0
192.168.152        link#4             UCS             4        0     en0
```

My example only has one physical interface, yours should have two, but one will be at a higher priority.

Regarding the further question, if there is another server with the same IP address as the one you are trying to ssh to, then when you try to ARP the address you will likely get two responses.  The order the responses arrive will probably determine which server you connect to.  I should hopefully not have to state that this a bad thing.

BTW unless you really know what you are doing (I assume it's for redundancy), this kind of setup can bite you hard.  I would recommend you closely evaluate your need to have two physically separate networks with the same network address.

Comment: Actually I had understood it as you describe.  Reviewing the routing tables will still determine the physical interface used.  My description however was poor as I did not explain that I was answering the second question after the routing table clearly

Comment: @Mike W.  I have re-read.  We disagree on what the OP setup is.  I assumed that he has two physical networks with the same address, but I also assumed he was not trying to communicate between them.  I assumed that he has a server connected to both and also another machine connected to both and wants to know which physcial network would be used to contact the server from the other machine.  Maybe we should clarify this first...

Comment: And if you really MUST have two physically separate addresses with exactly the same subnet address range, then ensure your bridging device (the one with 2 NICs, one in each network) has its subnet masks defined to keep them separate from that machine's point of view.  Like 192.168.1.80/25 and 192.168.1.180/25 even though all other devices in both physical networks use 192.168.1.X/24